# Identifying problem in MIPS pipeline datapath

Tags: computer-architecture, cpu-pipelines, mips

[image]

I'm having trouble identifying a problem in this pipelined datapath. After executing an add instruction, there are 5 subsequent R-type instructions executed. However, we are assuming no data hazard, so no data dependencies that are relevant. That confuses me because that takes out the main issue with executing multiple R-type instructions. Could it be a structural hazard in which there's not enough resources to execute multiple instructions at the same time, thereby needing more hardware?

Comment: `After executing an add instruction …` one particular *R-Type* (*R*egister) instruction `… there are 5 subsequent R-type instructions executed` Well, should run like a charm. `I'm having trouble identifying a problem in this pipelined datapath.` How do you know there is one, and what do you know about it?

Comment: Mentor gave me this prompt to think about, and said there is a problem.

Comment: Well, are there any R-Type instructions the description of which shows something like *undefined*, *locked*/*interlocked*, *stall*?

Comment: No, there are none. Just "5 subsequent R-type instructions."

Comment: `are there`, as in *in the machine specification*, in Gerry Kane's *MIPS RISC Architecture*

Comment: No, it is unspecified